# Basic Auth Error Laravel 4

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

Now my task is to create a post but only authorised or logged in users can do that
I am using auth.basic for the purpose of post requests 
but each time i send a post request on /api/posts with login credentials 
(email and password) i get invalid credentials
My table name is Member

Auth.php

```
 <?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Authentication Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
    | This driver manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
    | attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'eloquent',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
    | is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
    |
    */

    'model' => 'Member',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
    | default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'members',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reminder Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the settings for password reminders, including a view
    | that should be used as your password reminder e-mail. You will also
    | be able to set the name of the table that holds the reset tokens.
    |
    | The "expire" time is the number of minutes that the reminder should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'reminder' => array(

        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

        'table' => 'password_reminders',

        'expire' => 60,

    ),

);
```

Member.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Member extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'password'
    ];

    protected $table = 'members';

    protected $hidden = array('password');

    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

PostsController.php

```
class PostsController extends ApiController {

    protected $postTransformer;

    /**
     * PostsController constructor.
     * @param PostTransformer $postTransformer
     */
    function __construct(PostTransformer $postTransformer)
    {

        $this->postTransformer = $postTransformer;

        $this->beforeFilter('auth.basic', ['on' => 'post']);

    }
```

Routes.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function(){

    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');

});
```

Member Table

```
`USERID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```